# Hibernate HQL select distinct

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have an HQL query where I need to get distinct results. The problem is that I'm joining and eagerly fetching in a ton of other tables, and the underlying sql query that ends up being executed has distinct in there, but there's no way that those results can be distinct since it's selecting all of the columns from all of the joined entities. Hibernate then seems to perform some "magic" on the resultset that comes back to ensure that I do get distinct results of the entity that I want, but it seems wasteful for it to actually be running a distinct on the underlying SQL query. The query is something like:

```
select distinct a from com.blah.A a
inner join fetch a.b b
inner join fetch b.r
left outer join fetch b.c
inner join fetch a.d
inner join fetch a.e
```

Of course, this isn't the actual query, but it's a vague idea of what I'm doing. Is it desired functionality for the underlying to have a distinct in it even though Hibernate will still have to do some filtering when the query returns to make sure I only get distinct "A" entities? Seems wasteful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use either

1) Criteria Queries

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

2) Groovy SQL

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Tutorial+6+-+Groovy+SQL

This might help you. Thanks.

Comment: I tried the criteria route at first, but it was giving the same results. I was hoping to avoid writing pure SQL in this case, but it looks like that may be my best option since Hibernate doesn't give me the ability to do a Union.

Answer (score 0):

Never used HQL , as Biswas, I normally uses createCriteria, but if the query is returning domain objects, and you want only distinct results,you may try to define as a Set instead of a def, this will fix that you will not get multiple times on the final result.

Comment: That would definitely get rid of the duplicates in the code, but the issue I'm having is that the query is returning so many rows from the DB level and therefore taxing the DB pretty hard. I want the duplicates to be eliminated at the DB level rather than in code.

Answer (score 0):

Joins are very simple in hibernate, use createAlias and JoinType. Distinct is a little tricky, we have to use projections for all required fields, then we can add Projections.distinct to the field that should be distinct and do a resultTransform to bean. Find below an example:

```
    Criteria criteria = getHibernateSession().createCriteria(A.class);
    criteria.createAlias("b", "b", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
    criteria.createAlias("b.r", "b.r", JoinType.INNER_JOIN);
    criteria.createAlias("b.c", "b.c", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
    projectionList.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("a")), "a");
    // ADD all the fields that u want in projection
    criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
    criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(A.class));
    return criteria.list();
}
```